# codeigniter - select from 2 tables with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The problem in this model, is that if no records found in `imagini_produse`, the `id_produs` from `$this->_table` will be empty because will be replaced with the empty `id_produs` from `imagini_produse` table.

How can I avoid this?

```
function entries_by_limit($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("$this->_table a");
    $this->db->join('imagini_produse b', "b.id_produs = a.id_produs", "left");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    //print_r($this->db->last_query());
    return $result->result();
}
```

Comment: Try hard code table name `$this->db->from("some_table_name a");` and also try with return `$result->result_array();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check code.

```
function entries_by_limit($limit=100, $start=0) {
    $this->db->select('a.sameColumnName as Acolumn, b.sameColumnName as Bcolumn');
    $this->db->from($this->_table ." as a");
    $this->db->join('imagini_produse b', "b.id_produs = a.id_produs", "left");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
    return $result->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function entries_by_limit($limit=100, $start=0) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from("your_table_name a");
    $this->db->join('imagini_produse b', "b.id_produs = a.id_produs", "left");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    print_r($this->db->last_query());
    return $result->result();
}
```